# Fetch monthly records by total and by detail from single query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, subquery

I am working with SQL Server 2005.

I want to fetch `monthlyTotalAppoinment` and `monthlyEmployeewiseTotal` from `appointment` table in single result.

**Appointment Table**

```
appoinmentId
appoinmentDate
employeeId
```

I can successfully fetch `monthlyTotalAppoinment` and also got `employeewisetotaappoinment` from following query, but I want monthly `employeewiseappoinment`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT Datename(M, Dateadd(M, NUMBER - 1, 0)) AS month 
          FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES 
         WHERE TYPE = 'p' 
               AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 12) months 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Datename(MM, APPOINMENTDATE) month, 
                         Count(APPOINMENTID)          AS TotalAppointment 
                    FROM APPOINTMENT 
                   GROUP BY Datename(MM, APPOINMENTDATE)) appoinment 
              ON months.MONTH = appoinment.MONTH
```

I am getting following output.

[image]

but I want following output

[image]

```
   appoinementId   employeeId   appoinemntDate  
   -------------  -----------   ---------------
    1                 4         8/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    2                 4         8/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    3                 4         8/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    4                 4         8/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    5                 4         8/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    6                 4         9/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    7                 2         9/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    8                 2         9/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    9                 2         9/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    10                4         9/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    11                4         10/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    12                2         10/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
    13                4         10/25/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

for above data cuming output(For EmployeeId 4)

```
   Month           MonthData   Totalappoinemnt TotalEmployeewiseAppointmemt  
   -------------  -----------   -------------- ------------------------------
     January..      NULL..       NULL..          NULL..
     Augest         Augest         5             9
     September      September      5             9
     October        October        3             9
```

But i want following

```
     Month           MonthData   Totalappoinemnt TotalEmployeewiseAppointmemt  
   -------------  -----------   -------------- ------------------------------
    January..      NULL..       NULL..          NULL..
     Augest         Augest         5             5
     September      September      5             2
     October        October        3             2
```

Comment: What if the data is spread over multiple years, you would sum all year's januaries into one group.

Comment: no not at all, i didn't take consideration of year.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you want to do. Can you post some sample data for us?

Comment: OK, now I understand, Writing a query right now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing some minor points in your question, but the big issues are dealt with in this query:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.EMP_COUNT 
  FROM (SELECT Datename(MONTH, APPOINEMNTDATE) Month_Name, 
               Count(*)                        app_count 
          FROM APPOINTMENTTABLE 
         GROUP BY Datename(MONTH, APPOINEMNTDATE))T1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(*)                        emp_count, 
                         Datename(MONTH, APPOINEMNTDATE) Month_Name 
                    FROM APPOINTMENTTABLE 
                   WHERE EMPLOYEEID = 4 
                   GROUP BY Datename(MONTH, APPOINEMNTDATE))T2 
              ON t1.MONTH_NAME = t2.MONTH_NAME
```

A working example can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a459f/15).

What is missing?

1. Couldn't figure out why you had 2 columns for months. If there is a reason for this I'll revise the code.
2. I only listed months with details available. I saw that January was also in the example. If you want all 12 months to show even if no data is available, let me know and it will be added.
3. Didn't use the exact same column names. I'm sure you can change them if you need to :-)